# Why doesn't alum coagulate my cyanobacteria?

Tags: microbiology, limnology

My collected rainwater has a pronounced blue-green tint which I believe to be due to the presence of cyanobacteria.
I have been trying to remove the cyanobacteria using aluminium sulphate, but it doesn't seem to work.
Would anyone like to suggest why?

Comment: Do you have a good microsocope with which you could confirm the identity of the microscopic organisms?

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Unfortunately I didn't see your response for some reason.
I have come to the conclusion that the problem organism is not cyanobacteria.
I will ask another question to clarify the issue.